# vue3-openlayers view is permanently shifted to bottom

Tags: vue.js, openlayers

my view is shifted like shown below

actually is is shifter because there is a sort of padding in the `view` inde the `map` container as far as I can tell

drag the map up and it disapears
drag the map dow it is still there

I have some custom controls that are tied to the map with `absolute` and they are thrown outside because it seems that the origin is wrong. Not sure if this is related

[image]

Answer (score 1):

it was multiple conflicting map heights
Having a single map height solved the issue